# Including " in a regular expression using sed on windows

Tags: regex, sed

I have:

```
echo finally came. 34^"This is the account of | sed "s:[1-9][0-9]["]:<a name=\"top\">&</a>:g"
```

and I need to get

```
finally came. <a name="top">34"</a>This is the account of
```

I have tried `sed "s:[1-9][0-9][\"]:<a name=\"top\">&</a>:g"` and `"s:[1-9][0-9][^"]:<a name=\"top\">&</a>:g"` without success

How do I achieve this in cmd using sed. I have already installed sed in Windows but I need to mach numbers which have `"` on their right side.

Comment: What do you get right now? Are you running it in Windows built-in command line, Powershell or Bash?

Comment: you should say whether you're using gnuwin32 , or a cygwin version from the cygwin shell.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used `sed` in Windows, but from what I can tell from your question, escaping seems to work in a similar way as in *nix. You are already escaping the `"` in your replacement, why not do the same thing in the pattern itself?

```
sed "s:[1-9][0-9]\":<a name=\"top\">&</a>:g"
```

Also, based on the assumption that the shell you are working with is similar to the classic *nix shells, I would use single instead of double quotes for the `sed` expression, which means that the double quotes don't need to be escaped:

```
sed 's:[1-9][0-9]":<a name="top">&</a>:g'
```

Answer (score 1):

this does it

gnuwin32 sed.

> `C:\Users\user>echo finally came. 34^"This is the account of | sed
>   "s:[1-9][0-9 ][\"]:^<a name=\"top\"^>\0"</a>":g"`
>   `finally came. <a name="top">34"</a>This is the account of`
>
> C:\Users\user>

And if you replace `\0` with `^&` it also works , in the above windows example.

And you can replace `"</a>"` with `^</a^>`  which is fine too

for cygwin

> `user@comp ~`
>   $ echo finally came. 34\"This is the account of | sed
>   "s:[1-9][0-9 ][\"]:\0:g"`
>
> `finally came. <a name="top">34"</a>This is the account of`

and you can replace `\0` with `&` in the above cygwin example

Comment: see my answer here for two c programs I recommend you compile, that help figure these things out http://superuser.com/questions/328611/getting-this-simple-regular-expression-to-match-in-grep